# Kernel module system call overriding

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, archlinux

I'm trying to override the open system call on 4.5.1-1-ARCH, with not much luck. I got no errors, but the custom_open function is never called, so it's not actually overridden.

Code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static void **sys_call_table = NULL;

static asmlinkage long (*old_open) (const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);

static asmlinkage long custom_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
      printk(KERN_INFO "Custom open invoked");

      return old_open(filename, flags, mode);
}

static int init(void)
{
    sys_call_table = (void *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
    pr_info("sys_call_table address: %p\n", sys_call_table);

    old_open = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = custom_open;

    pr_info("Original open: %p; New open: %p\n", old_open, custom_open);

    return 0;
}

static void exit(void)
{
        pr_info("exit");
        sys_call_table[__NR_open] = old_open;
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(exit);
```

When the module is loaded, I get the following in dmesg:

```
[ 8027.331315] sys_call_table address: f97fe204
[ 8027.331320] Original open:   (null); New open: f97fc000
```

Comment: Note that changing pointers in `sys_call_table` is disabled in modern Linux kernels, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a local symbol sys_call_table.

Don't you think it is suspicious that the old open is null? What's more interesting is the fact that found address of the sys_call_table symbol is not far off from the address of custom_open. This is a strong hint that what you found is the address of your own sys_call_table symbol.'

What are you trying to achieve?

As a side note I just verified that pages backing the syscall table are mapped read-only, so if a mere write did not crash the kernel, you know you did not find it.

EDIT:

So, I checked arch config and the local find is likely a side effect of CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL not being set. This also means that kallsyms will be unable to find the symbol you want, but this should not matter much.

The module at http://maitesin.github.io/Module_prank/ is of unnecessarily poor quality and must not be used. I encountered it some time ago and explained major flaws here: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4b757p/linux_kernel_module_example_rickroll_prank/d16q5v5

Since you are just playing around, this kind of activity is not useful, especially at this stage. I can only recommend you stick to userspace for the time being.

Comment: The code is party from here: http://maitesin.github.io//Module_prank/
The full code also produces it, but it's supposed to be a working example. I don't know what am I missing here.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to learn more about how the modules, and the kernel itself works, but thanks a lot for your help. Could you recommend some more quality resources on the subject?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Design-Implementation-FreeBSD-Operating-Edition/dp/0321968972/ref=dp_ob_title_bk http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Internals-Frontiers-Uresh-Vahalia/dp/0131019082